# Using the %{HTTP_HOST} variable for session.save_path in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to write an .htaccess file that will be placed on a number of different sites, and I don't want to have to change the domain in the session.save_path for each site. I'm trying to use the %{HTTP_HOST} variable but it's not working.

The paths to the session storage folders on the server look like this:

```
/var/foo/vhosts/siteone.com/httpdocs/session/
/var/foo/vhosts/sitetwo.com/httpdocs/session/
```

So I'm trying to make this work dynamically, regardless of domain name. Here's what I've got that doesn't work:

```
php_value session.save_path /var/foo/vhosts/%{HTTP_HOST}/httpdocs/session
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported by apache. See the paragraph titled "URL Rewriting" at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/env.html#using.

An alternative solution could be setting an auto-prepend file in which you then set the save_path.

In .htaccess:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/prepend.php
```

In prepend.php:

```
<?php
session_save_path("/var/foo/vhosts/{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/httpdocs/session");
```

See:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file
2. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php